# Google map displaying only after pressing F12

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I followed exactly the coding structure given as per google map javascript api docs.

My code is as follows:

```html
<div id="googleMap" style="height:400px;width:100%;"></div>
  <script>

   function initMap() {
    var uluru = {lat: <?php echo $row->lat;?>, lng: <?php echo $row->lng;?>};
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('googleMap'), {
    zoom: 10,
    center: uluru
    });
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: uluru,
    map: map,
    title: '<?php echo $row->location;?>'
    });
    }



    </script>
    <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCLd0QoINJ8KgKpdNTqM-FIHY3svBFbTbQ&callback=initMap">
    </script>
```

You can go to: https://www.eventspub.com/eventview.php?eid=120 
and click Location tab to see the blank map page. Only after pressing F12 ( in Chrome) it works. Please advice.

Comment: Here's your code in a fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/jaromanda/8trcw716/ - with appropriate values to replace the PHP stuff, it works fine - see for yourself - do you see any errors in the **developer** tools console?

Comment: Thank you Jaromanda for your reply. Yes, it works fine in your fiddle. I'm using the same code with only one addition that is the API key. 
If you go to https://www.eventspub.com/eventview.php?eid=120 and click the location you can see the map area. There is no console errors, which surprised me. The map is completely blank unless I press the F12 key. Please advice.

Comment: Try different browsers

Comment: I just tried Microsoft Edge. Same results. After pressing F12 the map is shown.

Comment: The problem is that the DIV containing the MAP is "display:none" when `initMap` is called ... F12 does bugger all for me, by the way ... running `initMap()` in the console is what makes it work. Looks like you got some thinking to do about how to run `initMap()` when that "tab" is selected

Comment: Thank you Jaromanda, The issue is finally solved.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the template tab module which hides the element and won't run the initMap() Function.

I copied the Map display code outside the Tab:

```html
 <div id="googleMap" style="height:400px;width:100%;display: none; "></div>
 <script>

  function initMap() {
    var uluru = {lat: <?php echo $row->lat;?>, lng: <?php echo $row->lng;?>};
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('googleMap'), {
      zoom: 10,
      center: uluru
    });
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: uluru,
      map: map,
      title: '<?php echo $row->location;?>'
    });
  }



 </script>

 <script async defer src="//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOURAPIKEY&callback=initMap"></script>
```

Now in the Tab location button a javascript function when onclick event happens:

```html
<li ><a href="#h2tab3" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" onclick="showCustomMap()"><i class="fa fa-envelope pr-5"></i>Location Map</a></li>
```

Now the JS script is made to display the div map element and also call the initMap() function:

```js
function showCustomMap() {

  document.getElementById('googleMap').style.display = "block";
  initMap();

 }
 function hideCustomMap() {

  document.getElementById('googleMap').style.display = "none";

 }
```

Also, hideMap() function is called when other tabs are clicked to hide the independent map div.

The map is working flawlessly. Thanks to Jaromanda X for helping me diagnose the issue.